# ¿Como hacer el corrimiento en ensamblador?

Tags: bucles, ensamblador

Estoy solicitando un poco de ayuda porque aun no me queda claro como empezar.
Tengo que hacer un programa en lenguaje ensamblador que mediante una selección dada a traves de un registro se pueda llevar un corrimiento pero dado en las funciones LSR, ASR, LSL, ROR y RRX y con esto quiero decir que si mientras no se cambie la opción este se mantendraejecutando la instrucción de corrimiento.
Soy nuevo usando ensamblador y mas aplicado con un microprocesador TIVA c series y aun no me queda claro del todo por donde empezar.
Entiendo lo de los registros y que debe ser un ciclo peor no me queda del claro todo por donde empezar mi codigo.
De antemano agradezco su atención.

Comment: ¿No te pasaron algún pdf, pagina o referencia donde debas leer acerca de ello en tu materia?

Comment: @EdgarGc Lo vimos pero no tan bien explicado en clase y estuve tratando de investigar por mi cuenta sobre las funciones pero aun no me queda clar como utilizarlas del todo

Comment: te comento porque recuerdo que, en ensamblador no hay "bucles" como tal, sino creas una subrutina, una bandera y con los GOTO vas decrementando el valor de los registros hasta llegar a un valor determinado el cual te indica que, la bandera se cumple y, asi puedes generar las estructuras de control.